# Splitting a list based on another list that contains the indexes that must be filtered

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy, indexing

The problem is the following:

I have list of 91 ordered values each representing 1 of 2 possible trials: Pumpindex

I have another list (actually a pandas df) which has 2 columns, one called Left and the other Right. These columns contain the order in which left and right trials came in the first list. (i.e. column Left : 0,1,3,4,6,8... // column Right : 2,5,7,9....)

What i want to do next is split the first list based on their index if its index # is in either the left or Right column lists.

This is the most simple solution i came up with but alas it does not work and only filters out the first 46 left trials regardless of the number in the second list. It only sees that there 46 left trials and takes the first 46 trials from the first list.

```
 df1 = pd.read_csv("LeftRightrat1.csv")
 df1.columns = ['Left', 'Right']
 Pumpindex = [somelist]
 Leftypump = [x for x in Pumpindex if Pumpindex.index(x) in df1['Left']]
```

What i think i m doing here is: Add x to the list if the index of x is found in the series df1['Left']. So if the numbers 0,1,3,4,6,8 are in the df1[left] then my list would select only the values in Pumpindex that are indexed as 0,1,3,4,6,8. Unfortunately it only gives me 0,1,2,3,4,5...

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dataframe contains the indices for the split, why not try

```
left = [Pumpindex[x] for x in df1.Left]
right = [Pumpindex[x] for x in df1.Right]
```

Comment: That worked splendidly thanks for the swift reply! i just had to make sure there were no nan values in the  dataframe!

Thanks a bunch!